# Non-nullable instance field _repository must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU35B.png)

Non-nullable instance field '_repository' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.dartnot_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field in the flutter

Comment: Please dont add your code as images and please provide more details - what are you trying to achieve, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Dart constructors don't use their body to initialize properties. What you are looking for is the following snippet:

```dart
class NewsService {
  Repository _repository;

  NewsService() : _repository = Repository();
}
```

Comment: this is not working my flutter version is Flutter version 3.0.2

but this say to me (on-nullable instance field '_repository' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.dartnot_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field)

HELP ME I do not understand what i do

Comment: With the constructor in the code snippet of my answer you won't get that error. Compare my code to the code in your screenshot. Instead of the curly brackets `{}` you must use `:`